# How to add (or skip) projects to CV in a professional way?

Tags: resume, applications, germany, projects

I checked the forum and other online materials about what to state in the CV and what not to. Regarding projects, I couldn't find a unanimous agreement. I've heard from 1-2 recruiters that they prefer to see the significant projects in the CV, even with a short 1-2 line description for each of them, while other recruiters emphasized that one shouldn't name any project in the CV at all and leave them out for the motivation letter.

My field is computer science, but I'm not sure if it is related to the field or not.

Comment: As you said yourself, you can't find a unanimous agreement. You wont, because this is opinion based. There isn't 1 unanimous answer. Everyone will have their own opinion on what is best. Every recruiter will also have a different opinion about what is best. So what has been successful for 1 person wont for another etc... -- I personally say, if you have a personal project that's really good, and completely your own work, not a tutorial follow along, then include it.

Comment: For projects that are tutorial follow along, I'd only expect to see them in a junior's CV.

Comment: You may want to reword this question a bit, so it asks a very specific question, or it'll probably end up being closed.

Comment: @flexi any suggestion on how to reword it?

Comment: @flexi Yes, I tried to put only the recent and important projects that are significantly related to what I'm applying for. But in that case, do I need to create a separate section in the CV as the Selected Projects or I should put 1-2 bullet points under the job title in the work experience?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "projects"? Was it freelance work? Projects you did while you were employed by a company? Personal projects?

Comment: Consider listing technologies.  Projects are so they can tell if you have tried delivering something finished, and what impact it had.

Answer (score 3):

Thing is: there is no **"one golden CV fit for all job"** solution. You need to custom-build the CV for every job (or the job profile).

- Study the job profile and understand the key requirements.

  - For experienced professionals, they should explain briefly about only the projects which are relevant to the job / role/ position being applied for. Other related projects and non-related one may appear in a bulleted point at the bottom, if you can show they add value to the job / position being applied for.
  - For freshers / juniors, if there is any freelancing / part-time work done which relates to the industry, that is very important. Then, any project / work done as part of on-job training / certification is priority, then any university/ college project which has relevance to the work domain. Rest, again, might be skipped altogether or warrant a mention in the bottom one-liner, if at all.
- The items are generally written in reverse chronological order- most recent one at top and the oldest one at bottom.

Remember, the CV is your first impression, it has to be focused and short enough to draw attention, at the same time, long enough to cover the main subjects/ points. You need to find the right balance. It's not easy, but with practice and more googling you'll learn.

Answer (score 1):

1. One of the most important functions of the CV is to get you through the first round of resume scanning by an HR staffer
2. These people often know very little about the actual job, have to scan a lot of resumes in a sort time and have the attention span of a hamster
3. Hence you should keep it short: 1 page max for a junior & mid level, 2 pages for senior/principal and beyond
4. Organize it visually well, make sure someone can see the most relevant details in 30 seconds or less.
5. Now you can focus on the content: Start with a chronological list of your entire education & work history. At least company name, job title, start date, end date.
6. On a separate sheet create a list of your major accomplishment, results and achievements. Not what you did, but what the RESULT of your work was.
7. Sort your achievements "importance". That's a function of both the size of the impact and how long ago it was. Newer stuff is more important. Higher impact stuff is more important.
8. Now add achievements to your chronological list starting with the most important one. Continue until you either run out of space, your are out of achievements or you find your self adding fluff.

So if you did recent high-impact projects the results of these projects should show up in your CV. If you wrote some code 10 years ago that nobody used for anything, than leave it off.

Comment: What do you mean by "add achievements to your chronological list starting with the most important one"? Should one create a third section in the CV named something like "selected projects"? or should I add those selected projects under each job title in the "work experience" section?

Comment: How should I show if a project was a "High impact stuff" one?!