# Removing irrelavant skills from resume for specific jobs

Tags: job-search, resume

Is it a good idea to remove skills that are irrelavant to the job you are applying for from your resume.  Say the job is hiring a web developer and you know IOS or iphone programming and you know there is a 0% chance this job will need that skill, should you just get rid of that skill since it doesn't pertain to the job at all?

Having irrelavant skills will make the employer think that you are spread too thin or jack of all but master of none?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add (or skip) projects to CV in a professional way?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/167942/how-to-add-or-skip-projects-to-cv-in-a-professional-way)

Comment: Don't forget to proofread your resume! Minor spelling and punctuation errors can get under some people's skin and undermine their confidence in you...

Answer (score 4):

> Is it a good idea to remove skills that are irrelavant to the job you are applying for from your resume.

In general, Yes.

Including unrelated skills may distract from the relevant aspects you may have, and perhaps give the appearance that you were trying to fill the space up with. Besides, you want to keep your Resume brief and to the point; including unrelated skills takes valuable space that could have been used for skills or aspects that matter more.

This is "backed up" by the usual saying we say here that *"You should Tailor your resume for the specific job you are applying."*

On a more technical comment, iOS and Android development is not too unrelated to web development, so I wouldn't say that a web dev job will use 0% of those skills (for instance, web dev and iOS/Android dev both share things like UX/UI, material design, etc.).

Answer (score 3):

Make them less prominent - don't remove them.

The skills you have accumulated are a measure of your intelligence, your adaptability, your work ethic, your ability to work out of your comfort zone, constant self-improvement etc.   While they may not be 100% relevant to the job you're applying for, they indicate the type of person you are and what you can bring to the organisation. If it comes down to a head to head between you and another candidate you have no way of knowing what might break the tie - as such it makes sense to include anything that might give you an advantage.

What you should aim to do is mention non-relevant skills briefly and provide greater detail around skills that are more relevant. I think this is what people mean when they say "tailor your CV for the job". For example, for an architect position your CV would focus on languages and application design work you have done whereas for a team lead position you might highlight projects you've managed or time spent as a scrum master etc. I don't think it means remove anything that's not relevant entirely.

Even if you have spent a few years working in a completely different industry; list the position on your CV but don't go into any more detail than title, company and start end dates.  It won't result in a gap on your CV you'll need to explain and it also shows a drive to improve or an open mindedness to